# Edit by OP shows as edit by deleted user

Tags: bug, revisions-list

Have a look at [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/what-is-the-best-weapon-combination-in-modern-warfare-2/10989#10989).

The user card below it indicates that it was last edited by a deleted user; however, the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/10989/revisions) clearly shows that it was only ever touched by the OP.

So what went wrong here? (There are no other deleted answers on that question, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Looks like a merged account to me, but that still doesn't explain why two different Aardvarks are shown...

Comment: That was a year and a half ago.  It's likely that this works differently now.